# Android : alarmManager and Service

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I can start a Service with an AlarmManager and one PendingIntent ? I want that, when in my application there are not more data, the Service go down and the AlarmManager restart it after X minutes. It's possibile ?

Comment: Why comment? It's the correct answer.

Comment: But if I pass to AlarmManager the pending intent I must specify the flag...but there is a flag that start the pending intent without wake up the phone ? I read that this flag wake up the phone for start the pendingintent otherwise the pending intent start only when the user wake up the phone manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the AlarmManager flags ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or ELAPSED_REALTIME they can be used to deliver intents when the phone is in sleep, or when you manually wake up the phone.